# Standard deviation of pulling balls from two pools without replacement.

Tags: probability, statistics

We are given two different pools of balls. Pool 1 contains $N$ balls total, of which $K$ are red "target" balls, and $N-K$ white "non-target" balls. Pool 2 contains $N$ balls total, of which $J$ are green "target balls", and $N-J$ white "non-target" balls.

Someone then simultaneously pulls one ball from Pool 1 and one ball from Pool 2 and marks whether they pulled two targets simultaneously or not. This is repeated a total of $N$ times without replacement until the pools are both empty. The total number of times a red and green ball were simultaneously pulled is then recorded as the number of "hits".

If we calculate each possible permutation of pulls in Pool 1 and Pool 2 and plot the histogram of the total number of "hits", the average number of times someone should pull two target balls simultaneously should be equal to $N\cdot K/N\cdot J/N.$ (This is just the chance of two independent events occuring)

What would the PDF of this distribution be? Is there a way to write an equation for the probability of a specific number of hits occuring?

Comment: As a first step you should try to find the probability mass function of the distribution.

Comment: My reply missed the fact that you said "without". I'll see if I can revise it and then restore it.